# pre-loading module R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

For an 'output' that doesn't use `renderUI`, but is a module, such as:

```
modUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", ...),
      tabPanel("Summary", ...),
      tabPanel("Table", ... )
    )
}
```

What would be the equivalent to:

```
outputOptions(output, "ouname", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

to load in advance?

Comment: (1) your module should really *use* `ns`, as in `plotOutput(ns("plot"))`. (2) If you name the module's instance as `modUI("quux")`, then perhaps `outputOptions(output, NS("quux")("ouname"), ...)`? I'm using `shiny::NS` for completeness, though you could easily shortcut that to be `"quux-ouname"`, *I think*. Untested.

Comment: So yes, one needs to distinguish between the name assigned to the instance of the module, and the name assigned to each UI element. In the default case in `shiny`, they are just string-concatenated with `collapse="-"`, so I think you can use that knowledge to set options. I have no idea if it works, tbh, it might require that the id be found before setting options on it, in which case you may be stuck `observe`-ing for its creation and then setting the options *then*. Hope it works!

Comment: your approach work for renderUIs/outputs inside the module, but not for the module itself. I think a big problem is that while the inner output has the class shinyboundoutput, what I am trying to modify, tabs, is shiny bound input.

Comment: I see, your recent edit throws a wrench in things. If you don't know the ids of the components of a module, then you can only guess. Does `names(output)` give you any insight? (You'd need to run that within a reactive/observe block while running to see.)

Comment: Your answer is a valid answer. I just cannot pretend to use output options in something that is not an output, so it works!